# Detecting normal minus and numpad minus in JavaScript onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In JavaScript's event `onKeyDown`, is there anyway to differentiate a minus sign pressed in the "normal" keyboard area from one pressed in the numpad? I think they generate the same `which` code (at least in FireFox).

I'm trying to map an standard qwerty layout to a different keyboard mapping in a text area as a user types in, and want to ignore anything on the numeric pad.

Let me know if I'm unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to do it reliably cross-browser. There's an excellent writeup of keyboard events and the codes generated on various browsers [on this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). I think it's getting pretty dated now, though.